# Number Line Jumps Hacker Rank Question Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, formula

I passed the exercise which has the description below:
[image]

This is my code:

```
private static boolean findPosition(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {
         int n = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
         for(int i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
             if(x1 == x2) {
                 return true;
             } else {
                 x1 += v1;
                 x2 += v2;
             }
         }
         return false;
     }
     

    public static String kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {
    // Write your code here
        if( (x1 < x2 && v1 <= v2) || (x2 < x1 && v2 <= v1) ) {
            return "NO";
        } else {
            if(findPosition(x1,v1,x2,v2)) {
                return "YES";
            }
        }
        return "NO";
    }
```

But when I refer to another post, which also successfully passed the test case,
I met a formula : `(x2-x1)%(v1-v2)==0`

I've been trying to understand how the formula works failed :(

Can anyone help me understand this formula works

Comment: Always copy paste the problem statement instead of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula can be derived using basic algebra:

You can write an expression for the position of each kangaroo after some number of jumps, `j`:

```
p1 = x1 + j * v1
p2 = x2 + j * v2
```

Clearly if they are at the same position, `p1 = p2`, so:

```
x1 + j * v1 = x2 + j * v2
```

Rearranging for `j`:

```
j = (x2 - x1) / (v1 - v2)
```

Now, the particular value of `j` doesn't matter from the perspective of the question: you simply want it to be a whole number. For that to happen, the denominator has to divide the numerator.

In other words,

```
(x2 - x1) % (v1 - v2) == 0
```

There are (at least) a couple of edge cases to watch out for:

- You also probably want `(x2 - x1) / (v1 - v2) >= 0`, otherwise the kangaroos would only be at the same place in the past.
- You should handle the case where `v1 = v2` before applying the modulo operation - otherwise you'd get an `ArithmeticException`. There is a possibly valid solution in such a case, namely that `x1 = x2`.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what the formula says in words is: 
If the difference of the initial positions is a multiple of the difference of the velocities, then they will meet.

The `%` operator returns the remainder when the first number is divided by the second. So to check if `a%b==0` means to check if b divides a. Another common use is to check for odd numbers by checking if `a%2==1`.

In your problem, they are checking if the distance, say `d`, is divisible by the difference of the velocities. You can imagine fixing `x1` at a place, which would be equivalent to subtracting the velocity `v1` from `x2`. So if they meet, the difference in position should be a multiple of the new velocity `v2-v1`.